# Where are the entity DLL's stored

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity

I seem to be missing: `System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;` when creating a class library for my models, where would this dll be stored? and if its not there whats the next step?

Comment: That's a namespace in the EntityFramework.dll assembly, which you get from NuGet.

Comment: Ya that was my mistake I didn't realize you have to install entity in every new non MVC project